# How to get a random int from a multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

I'm looking to get a random int from a 2d array like this:

```
static const int points[6][3] = { {2,3,4}, {11,12,13}, {14,15,16}, {17,0,1}, {8,9,10}, {5,6,7} };
```

The output could be any number within the array.

Comment: Create a random number `x` in the range [0, 6*3 - 1] with [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and use it as index to access the array element: `points[x/3][x%3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) from `<stdlib.h>` in combination with `time` from `<time.h>`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
/* get random element */
int y = rand() % 6;
int x = rand() % 3;
int r = points[y][x];
```

Alternatively you could use [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which is preferable, as mentioned by [jabaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15388024) in the comments:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 5);
int y = distr(gen);
int x = distr(gen) % 3;
int r = points[y][x];
```